# What are the current staking and mining rewards for the Loki Network as of 2019-May?

Tags: mining, monero-forks, loki, staking

Loki is a cryptonote coin with staking and mining. What is the staking and mining reward calculation for the Loki Network as of today 2019-May-29? And what will it be in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the Loki [docs](https://lokidocs.com/ServiceNodes/StakingRequirement/), the LSR calculation is:

```
15000 + (25007/2^((h-101250)/129600))
```

Where `h` is the block height.

E.g. using current height `281798`:

```
$ perl -e 'print 15000 + (25007/2**((281798-101250)/129600));'
24521.1959709724
```

You can calculate the future LSR by simply increasing the block height.